# How to do LEFT JOIN in LINQ correctly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Here is my query. I want to do this in LINQ

```
SELECT tc.AppId, 
   tc.ConfigCode, 
   tc.ConfigId, 
   tc.ConfigType, 
   COALESCE(tm.ConfigValue, tc.ConfigValue) AS ConfigValue, 
    CASE 
      WHEN tc.ConfigType = 'Application' 
         THEN tc.AppId
      ELSE tm.Id
    END as Id,
FROM   dbo.Configs tc 
   LEFT JOIN dbo.ConfigValues tm 
          ON tc.ConfigId = tm.ConfigId
```

Here is my query and I don't get the correct results

```
db.Configs
.Join(db.ConfigValues.DefaultIfEmpty(), tc => tc.ConfigId, tm => tm.ConfigId, (tc, tm) => new { tc = tc, tm = tm })
.Select(r => new {
    AppId = (Guid?)r.tc.AppId,
    ConfigCode = r.tc.ConfigCode,
    ConfigId = r.tc.ConfigId,
    ConfigValue = (r.tm.ConfigValue ?? r.tc.ConfigValue),
    Id = (Guid)(r.tc.ConfigType == "Application" ? r.tc.AppId : r.tm.Id),
});
```

Comment: Have you tried a group join with the 'left' side having a default value?

Comment: See msdn webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query can look like

```
db.Configs
.LeftJoin(db.ConfigValues, tc => tc.ConfigId, tm => tm.ConfigId)
.Select(r => new {tc = r.Left, tm = r.Right})
.Select(r => new {
    AppId = (Guid?)r.tc.AppId,
    ConfigCode = r.tc.ConfigCode,
    ConfigId = r.tc.ConfigId,
    ConfigValue = (r.tm.ConfigValue ?? r.tc.ConfigValue),
    Id = (Guid)(r.tc.ConfigType == "Application" ? r.tc.AppId : r.tm.Id),
});
```

If you use the below extension methods. It will make your code more readable when using the fluent version of LINQ as well as reusable because you can use the LeftJoin/RightJoin in other LINQ queries.

```
public class LeftJoinResult
{
    public TLeft Left { get; set; }
    public TRight Right { get; set; }
}

public class RightJoinResult
{
    public TRight Right { get; set; }
    public TLeft Left { get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable> LeftJoin(this IQueryable left, IQueryable right, Expression> leftKeySelector, Expression> rightKeySelector)
    where TRight : class
{
    return left.GroupJoin(right, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, (l, r) => new
    {
        Left = l,
        Matches = r.DefaultIfEmpty(),
    })
    .SelectMany(j => j.Matches, (j, m) => new LeftJoinResult
    {
        Left = j.Left,
        Right = m,
    });
}

public static IQueryable> RightJoin(this IQueryable right, IQueryable left, Expression> rightKeySelector, Expression> leftKeySelector)
    where TLeft : class
{
    return right.GroupJoin(left, rightKeySelector, leftKeySelector, (r, l) => new
    {
        Right = r,
        Matches = l.DefaultIfEmpty(),
    })
    .SelectMany(j => j.Matches, (j, m) => new RightJoinResult
    {
        Right = j.Right,
        Left = m,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're only missing an DefaultIfEmpty(). The '?' in r.tm?.ConfigValue??... catches NullPointer of 'r.tm'

```
db.Configs
.Join(db.ConfigValues.DefaultIfEmpty(), tc => tc.ConfigId, tm => tm.ConfigId, (tc, tm) => new { tc = tc, tm = tm })
.Select(r => new {
    AppId = (Guid?)r.tc.AppId,
    ConfigCode = r.tc.ConfigCode,
    ConfigId = r.tc.ConfigId,
    ConfigValue = (r.tm.ConfigValue ?? r.tc.ConfigValue),
    Id = (Guid)(r.tc.ConfigType == "Application" ? r.tc.AppId : r.tm.Id)
}).DefaultIfEmpty(AppId = (Guid?)r.tc.AppId,
                  ConfigCode = r.tc.ConfigCode,
                  ConfigId = r.tc.ConfigId,
                  ConfigValue = (r.tm?.ConfigValue ?? r.tc.ConfigValue),
                  Id = (Guid)(r.tc.ConfigType == "Application" ? r.tc.AppId : r.tm.Id));
```